# How to remove first word only if it contains this?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a Javascript that removes the word "Process" only if it is included in the variable `str`. Sometimes `str` will have a different word in front of "cyan" and I want to keep it. Something is wrong with my 3rd line that is returning no results.

```
var str = 'process cyan';

str.replace(/\b./g, function(m){ return m.toUpperCase(); });

"process".replace('process','');
```

Comment: What do you expect that 3rd line to do?

Comment: The `.replace()` function returns a *new* string. The original string is not modified. Your third line doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Something is wrong with my 3rd line that is returning no results*

Your third line is indeed returning something.

```
"process".replace('process','');
```

It's returning the empty string (`''`). But you're not setting it to anything, like

```
var newstr = "process".replace('process','');
```

so you can't tell.

But the bigger problem is that while you want to change the value of `str` from `'process cyan'` to `' cyan'`, you are instead replacing a *new string* equal to `"process"`, with nothing.

What I think you want to do is

```
str = str.replace('process','');
```

Comment: str = str.replace('process',''); Worked but appears to put a space before the word Cyan. Need to eliminate the space

Comment: @Patrick that's because the replace function is doing exactly what you asked, not exactly what you meant.

Comment: Added space after the word "process" in the str

Comment: @Patrick To eliminate the space, you could also use `str = str.replace('process','').trim();`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var res = str.replace('Process','');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    var str = 'process test';//you string

    if(str!=='process cyan')
    {
            alert(str); //do u stuff here
    }

   else
    {
            var res = str.replace('process','');
    // replace process with string or what where u want
    }
```